# Get Closest point between a Box 3D and a Point

Tags: unity, collision-detection, mathematics

[image]

I have a point A (x, y, z),
and a Box: Center (x, y, z), Size (Width, Height)

How to get the closest point in the box from the point A ?

In Unity I can create a bound, and I can find the non-rotated position like that:

```
Bounds bounds = _mesh.bounds;
Vector3 closestPoint = bounds.ClosestPoint(pointA);
```

But then If the bound is rotated, the result is not correct.
So I have 2 options:

Find the way to rotate my closestPoint from the pivot.
Find the math formula myleft.

If someone can help ! thanks.

EDIT: here a video:
the red point is the one find with bound.ClosestPoint
the yellow point is the one find with:

```
Vector3 closestPointInverse = _currentTarget.InverseTransformPoint(closestPoint);
```

https://youtu.be/RMRRtSaJv8w

I have also tryed to do my own rotateFromPivot function:

```
public Vector3 RotatePointAroundPivot(Vector3 point, Vector3 pivot, Vector3 angles)
    {
        return Quaternion.Euler(angles) * (point - pivot) + pivot;
    }
```

When I use it, I get the same result with the InverseTransformPoint method.

Comment: Did you try first rotating the point into the mesh's coordinate space with transform.InverseTransformPoint?

Comment: I have edited my question: yes I have, see the result in the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that I said "first" not "after" - you're using the transform method backwards.

```
Vector3 ClosestPointOnMeshOBB(MeshFilter meshFilter, Vector3 worldPoint) {
     // First, we transform the point into the local coordinate space of the mesh.
     var localPoint = meshFilter.transform.InverseTransformPoint(worldPoint);

     // Next, we compare it against the mesh's axis-aligned bounds in its local space.
     var localClosest = meshFilter.sharedMesh.bounds.ClosestPoint(localPoint);

     // Finally, we transform the local point back into world space.
     return meshFilter.transform.TransformPoint(localClosest);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use **colliders** and **raycast**. tray to make a box collider for you box mesh. then cast a ray from point to center of box.

```
  void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            var ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
               print(hit.point);

            }
        }
    }
```

`hit.point` is nearest point t you empty object or point.